# Trouble installing GS from source

Tags: software-installation, make, ghostscript

I'm trying to install Ghostscript 9.23 from source, and getting some errors I'm not familiar with. I'm using CentOS.

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.9-67.ELsmp (brewbuilder@ls20-bc1-14.build.redhat.com) (gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-8)) #1 SMP Wed Nov 7 13:58:04 EST 2007
```

After `./configure` I run `make` and get the following errors...

```
./lcms2art/include/lcms2art.h:146:10: warning: "ULLONG_MAX" is not defined
./lcms2art/include/lcms2art.h:153:10: warning: "LLONG_MAX" is not defined
./lcms2art/src/cmsplugin.c: In function `_cmsReadFloat32Number':
./lcms2art/src/cmsplugin.c:195: warning: implicit declaration of function `fpclassify'
./lcms2art/src/cmsplugin.c:195: error: `FP_ZERO' undeclared (first use in this function)
./lcms2art/src/cmsplugin.c:195: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
./lcms2art/src/cmsplugin.c:195: error: for each function it appears in.)
./lcms2art/src/cmsplugin.c:195: error: `FP_NORMAL' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [obj/cmsplugin.o] Error 1
```

What does that mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: Why do you want build from source? Why don't you use package manager?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 - no errors were thrown if that's what you mean. lots of yesses and nos but it appeared to finish successfully.

Comment: @uzsolt - beacuse 1) yum doesn't install the latest version and 2) because I need to install it alongside an existing, older version. If there is a solution using yum that takes this into account please let me know, I'm not a centOS user, this is a server at work.

Comment: @Occam'sRazor this is a CentOS's drawback. Old but stable programs. Maybe it's your problem too: `FP_ZERO` and `FP_NORMAL` is define in `math.h` (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/math.h.html or http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/math.h.0p.html) - check your `math.h` and check it's included by GS. But I think it's not a good idea to pollute CentOS's filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the compiler pick up `math.h`, I added `-std=c99` to `LCMS2_CFLAGS` in the main `Makefile` once `configure` finished:

```
LCMS2_CFLAGS=-DSHARE_LCMS=$(SHARE_LCMS) -std=c99
```