# What is this GhostScript error? “/undefined in /BXlevel”

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, png

At first I thought this might have been a missing font issue but as far as I can tell from the output, GS is finding the font just fine..

Any hints as to what the problem might be?

```
$ /usr/bin/gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile="$RAWPNG" "$PDF_PATH/$PDF_FILENAME"


GNU Ghostscript 7.07 (2003-05-17)
Copyright (C) 2003 artofcode LLC, Benicia, CA.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Loading NimbusRomNo9L-Regu font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n021003l.pfb... 2471956 1102101 1642520 351150 0 done.
Using NimbusRomanNo9L-Regu font for NimbusRomNo9L-Regu.
Loading NimbusSanL-Regu font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n019003l.pfb... 2846916 1446739 1682712 365686 0 done.
Using NimbusSansL-Regu font for NimbusSanL-Regu.
Error: /undefined in /BXlevel
Operand stack:
   --dict:2/2(L)--   1   --dict:6/6(ro)(G)--   xref
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1062/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:93/200(L)--   --dict:93/200(L)--   --dict:97/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:229/230(ro)(G)--   --dict:16/24(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
GNU Ghostscript 7.07: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm noticing that you are using a very old GhostScript implementation.  The error was reported to the GhostScript bug database in 2006 as [bug #689876](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=689876) (for releases 8.54 and 8.62) and should be fixed in more recent versions of the tool.

The error also crops up in a number of other bug reports (all quite old), but my main suggestion would be to try with a more recent GhostScript. [The most recent release is 9.23](https://www.ghostscript.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid of that. Unfortunately [updating is out of the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461646/trouble-installing-gs-from-source). We'll have to send it over the wire to a newer server.

Comment: @Occam'sRazor Hmmm.... your whole system seems outdated. If this is a production system, I would strongly suggest that you do a proper update, to patch security related issues if not for any other reason.

Comment: Yeah, I know. We're updating things little by little. Not my call when specific things get done though.